# Are my SharePoint web front ends working properly? (load balancing)

Tags: sharepoint, iis-6, load-balancing, web-farm

I have SharePoint running on a server farm configured with 1 app server, 2 WFE's and 1 DB server. I have 4 applications in SharePoint which are (seemingly) working properly.

What is strange, however, is that only 2 of the applications' worker processes (running under their respective unique service accounts) are executing on the web front ends. This makes me think that the front ends aren't doing their job for the remaining 2 applications. Should I be concerned?

Also I'm not sure if 'load balancing' is the proper term for what should be happening here, though it seems to fit.

Comment: How did you configure the web servers to load balance? Did you use Microsoft native load balancing or are you using a 3rd party load balancer?

Comment: UPDATE: It appears this one may be caused by an ISA issue. I have my DNS pointing to only the webapp for the 'offending' applications likely causing only the app server to serve requests instead of load balancing. I should have the dns pointing to ISA which then should have rules to load balance. (I clearly don't manage ISA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe nobody is trying to access those two applications. If so, than the work process wont start. Just try to access them.

Comment: I think this may be the issue...but I'm not completely sure of it. I see one of the 2 'missing' processes running on one of the WFE's so I'll tentatively say they're just not being hit enough.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the processes should run only on the application server.

Answer (score 0):

What do your AAM mappings look like? That's a good place to look on this issue.